# How to send text to the search field through Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm trying to search for products on a shopping site.I test that a new page opens when I press the search button. But after typing it as search text, it remains on the main page.

```
self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".search-box").click()
self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".search-box").send_keys("samsung 20")
self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".search-icon").click()
self.driver.implicitly_wait(1000)
    actualUrl2 = "https://www.trendyol.com/srq=samsung%20s20&qt=samsung%20s20&st=samsung%20s20&os=1"
    expected2 = self.driver.current_url
    # self.assertEqual(actualUrl, expected)
    if (actualUrl2 == expected2):
        print("Welcome")
    else:
        print("Başarısız")
        print(expected2)
```

Comment: It worked for me, are you sure you clicked the initial popup?

Comment: When I ran the code, expected2 is = https://www.trendyol.com/giris?cb=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.trendyol.com%2Fbutik%2Fliste%2F2%2Fmale. And this is the main page

Answer (score 0):

Apply some `Waits`. And also `close the pop-ups` in the page.

```
# Imports Required:

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opts.add_argument("--disable-notifications")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path to chromedriver.exe",options=opts)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get("https://www.trendyol.com/")

# Close pop-ups
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME,"modal-close"))).click()
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME,"close-button"))).click()
except:
    pass

search = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".search-box")))
search.send_keys("samsung 20")
search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```